# How to convert to datetime and work with the row?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I have this code right here that I'm making a report, and I'm trying to work with the date but I cant cause pycharm says it cant work with "series" format, I`m trying to convert it to simple datetime but nothing works, can u guys help me?
the "DATA" is coming with the format of "datetime n 64" and I need it to be normal datetime, how can I do this?

```
 import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

class generate_report():

def __init__(self):
    self.csv = "output.csv"
    self.sql_conn = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver = '{SQL Server}',
                          server = 'localhost', database = 'MPWJ_BI')
    self.query = "select * from CTP_EXTRATO_GERAL where HISTORICO = 'Aplicação' order by data"
    self.df = pd.read_sql(self.query, self.sql_conn)
    self.df['DATA'] = pd.to_datetime(self.df['DATA'])
    self.df.to_csv(self.csv)

def analyze_data(self):
    pd.read_csv(self.csv)

    print(self.df.dtypes)
```

Comment: Could you please update your question with the output of `df.head()` and the expected output? This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) should get you started.

Comment: I just want to change the type, from datetime n64 to normal datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your date looks like

for example

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2020 7:31PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
```

documentation
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

EDIT:

To convert from datetime64 to datetime you can do the following:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np


# Current time UTC
dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

# Convert to datetime64
dt64 = np.datetime64(dt)

# convert to epoch
ts = (dt64 - np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00')) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')

# Convert to datetime
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts))
```

Comment: how can I convert it from datetime n64 to normal datetime using it? I used pd.to_datetime and did not work